# Can i use templatetags inside inclusion tags?

Tags: django, django-templates

I wrote a inclusion tag and two templatetags for rendering a voting code as html, [here you can see](https://github.com/miratcan/qhonuskan-votes/blob/be25ccb7167a11d3a11c6901a5d6c6e2b5e81132/qhonuskan_votes/templatetags/qhonuskan_votes.py).

As you see there is a vote_buttons_for inclusion tag for rendering [vote_buttons.html](https://github.com/miratcan/qhonuskan-votes/blob/be25ccb7167a11d3a11c6901a5d6c6e2b5e81132/qhonuskan_votes/templates/vote_buttons.html). Inside the template, i am trying to use **is_up_voted_by**, and **is_down_voted_by** templatetags in same file. It renders template but templatetags are not working without giving any errors.

Do you have any idea about why can it happening like this?

Answer (score 2):

The included template, **vote_buttons.html requires a {{ user }} context variable. [vote_button_for](https://github.com/miratcan/qhonuskan-votes/blob/be25ccb7167a11d3a11c6901a5d6c6e2b5e81132/qhonuskan_votes/templatetags/qhonuskan_votes.py#L6) does not return a dict with a 'user' item**. Assuming {{ user }} should be the request user, you could use something like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('vote_buttons.html',takes_context=True)
def vote_buttons_for(context, object, *args, **kwargs):
    return {
        "user": context['user'],
        "object": object,
        "vote_model": "%s.%sVote" % (
            object._meta.app_label, object._meta.object_name)
    }
```

Comment: Yeah i realized that after asking. As a note to append request.user to that context, inclusion tag should have `takes_context=True` paremeter. After that you can append user object as `"user": context['user']`... you can [click here](https://github.com/miratcan/qhonuskan-votes/blob/fc9d0564d491541f6192892544c4d2b253561872/qhonuskan_votes/templatetags/qhonuskan_votes.py#L32) to see.

Comment: Please close the question, I just opened it again to see if I could improve my answer... Should have spent the time working on an open question.